# how to structure an output file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
string[] number= new string[]{"1","2","3"};
string[] make= new string[]{"BMW","Nissan","Honda"};
string[] color=new string[]{"black","silver","white"};
```

I want to output the strings in a file with the following structure.

1 BMW black

2 Nissan Silver

3 Honda white

Comment: And what is the problem? What have you tried doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
 sb.Append($"{number[i]} {make[i]} {color[i]} \n");
}
File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString());
```

By using string builder and File(System.IO) you can do it.

Comment: there will be a trailing '\n', you can remove it in case it could create any issues by trimming last 2 positions from the stringbuilder.

Comment: actually, the \n is needed to change the line.